# How to received data from arduino using bluetooth flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth

**I am able to connect and send data to arduino but I don't know how I can received data from arduino. Please help me.**

I am using **flutter_bluetooth_serial** package

**Send message to arduio code here:**

```
Future<bool> sendMessage(String text) async {
    if (connected != false) {
      //await connectToBluetooth();
      text = text.trim();
      connection!.output.add(Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(text + "\r\n")));
      await connection!.output.allSent;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
   
  }
```

Comment: if you have `connection!.output` there is also `connection!.intput` - more: [BluetoothConnection](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bluetooth_serial/latest/flutter_bluetooth_serial/BluetoothConnection-class.html) - the docs say: *"Stream sink used to read from the remote Bluetooth device"*

Answer (score 2):

If you bonded the device and have the address you can start a stream to listen to the changes like so:

```
connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(server.address);
connection!.input!.listen((event) {
print(event);
}
```

from the Arduino side you can make the bluetooth to send data like:

```
bluetooth.write(-1) // for numbers;
bluetooth.print(str) // for strings;
```

Comment: Actually I want received a response data from arduino  after sending data to to arduino. How I can do it?

Comment: start the listener after sending the message and stop it when the response received and so on

Comment: @LMech Can you provide an example?